# Creating a raster from a vector file (single data points)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I am trying to create a raster from a vector file that is made out of point coordinates.
My data looks like following and that's the error that jumps out, when trying.

[image]

Comment: Supposedly your data doesn't exist.

Comment: Try saving the csv layer as a geopackage point layer. Can you show the parameter settings you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't rasterize point layer, because raster layers has to be rectangular. If you want a continues surface, the best option is interpolation. There are many methods of interpolation, with the most common one the IDW.
You can read more about the methods here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html